# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './reportWebVitals' in 'C:\Users\Robert Langdon\Documents\MERN\React\01tut\src' "webpack compiled with 1 error"

Tags: reactjs, web-vitals

I'm new to React, I just set up the whole thing and when I run the command "npm run start" I am getting the error :

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './reportWebVitals' in 'C:\Users\Robert Langdon\Documents\MERN\React\01tut\src
```

I have attached the snapshot of the error:
[Screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6J5Ch.png)

I have looked out for the similar problem and I have tried everything it still throws error, I have tried the following steps ways :

```
1. npm install --save-dev web-vitals
2. I have tried Deleting node_modules and reinstall the dependencies.
3. I have already checked for devDependencies in my package.json
```

Please help out I'm stuck here

Answer (score 0):

ReportWebVitals is a file inside of src/ . So make sure that the file exists. If it doesn't, then add it in (reportWebVitals.js).

[image]

Make sure that it also has the right code in it:

[image]

Your error is module not found so I have the feeling that the file isn't actually there at all!

If you can, please provide the source code if this doesn't work!